# Twig tag cannot get resolved inside nav_widget tag

Tags: twig, yii2

Code is as below:

```
{{ nav_widget({
'options': {
'class': 'navbar-nav navbar-right',
},
'items': [
{ 'label': "Welcome, {{ app.user.identity.username }}", 'items': [ { 'label': 'Logout', 'url': '/site/logout', 'linkOptions': { 'data-method': 'post' } } ] }
]
}) }}
```

If the logged in username is 'James', but what displayed on web is still `{{ app.user.identity.username }}`. Thus the twig tag `{{ app.user.identity.username }}` is not resolved in such case.

Any suggestions?

Note: this is also raised as an [issue in Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8101).

Comment: Please use code tags when posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set concatenate strings you should set with `~`. `"Welcome, " ~ app.user.identity.username`

```
  {{ nav_widget({
    'options': {
    'class': 'navbar-nav navbar-right',
    },
    'items': [
    { 'label': "Welcome, " ~ app.user.identity.username, 'items': [ { 'label': 'Logout', 'url': '/site/logout', 'linkOptions': { 'data-method': 'post' } } ] }
    ]
    }) }}
```

See [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators)